# Dragging object to wrong position and Scrolling of panel in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working for one application in C#, in which I have to show some control in a panel. Controls can be dragable. All is working fine except one thing, mentioned as follows

- Suppose i have a panel(controls container) in Main-Panel. Main panel has AutoScroll property true.So Main-Panel shows scroll bars when inner panel(controls container) has the height more than the height of Main-Panel.
- suppose inner panel is showing in two areas due to large height than main-panel.When i add a picturebox in inner panel,  then picturebox is showing in upper area, because i set the location 10,10 in start.
- when i try to drag this picturebox to down,it move with the mouse movement.If picturebox enters in lower area of inner panel, scrollbars of Main-panel automatically go down and mouse position is automatically go down according to current position and picturebox also goes down to that position.but it was not desirable position.
  my code is simple for moving objects.

  ```
  public static void Init(Control control, Control container, Direction direction)
  {
      bool Dragging = false;
      Point DragStart = Point.Empty;
      control.MouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
      Dragging = true;
          DragStart = e.Location;
          control.Capture = true;
          HoldOn.Invoke(sender, e);

      };

      control.MouseUp += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          Dragging = false;                               
          control.Capture = false;

      };

      control.MouseMove += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          if (Dragging)
          {

              control.Location =  new Point(e.X - DragStart.X + control.Location.X,
              e.Y - DragStart.Y + control.Location.Y);


          }
      };
  }
  ```

I have added a picture to show my problem.
I hope it will help for you to understand.
[image]

Comment: The Location you calculate needs to be offset by the panel's AutoScrollPosition.  What you are trying to do is very hard to implement in an intuitive way, you want the mouse to move but not the control.

Comment: I want the control to move with mouse but it jumps down directly in end of the panel or page due to jumping down of the scrollbars.
I want it to move/drag slowly to down and also scroll bars move slowly not jumps down to end of page directly.